# Can I assume that on android SDL registers main screen as touch device 0? Or else how do I get main screen id?

Tags: sdl, sdl-2

As `SDL_GetNumTouchDevices()` suggests, SDL supports multiple touch devices.

Can I assume that `SDL_GetTouchDevice(0)` will return an ID of the main screen?

If I can't then how do I figure out which one of them is the main screen?

Answer (score 0):

I used index 1 and it worked.
I was testing on a BlackBerry Key2, which technically has two touch inputs (the keyboard is capacitive as well as the screen) so I don;t know if that might have been the reasn for my success. I gave that function the index 1 - SDL_GetTouchDevice(1) - and it worked. I can succsessfully detect touch inputs!

```
if (event.type == SDL_FINGERDOWN && SDL_GetNumTouchFingers(1) == 2)
{
    interface->getMainMenu().setShowMainMenu();
}
```

So here SDL_GetNumTouchFingers(1) takes in the DeviceID index. I provided the value of 1 and it worked :)